# Will (GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline)Gamekit framework in Online Mode find peers over the internet or only in local Wifi network?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

In my iphone application i want to do peer to peer connections over the internet. So does GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline in Gamekit framework support P2P over the internet or is it only for local Wifi Network.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Documentation - GKPeerPickerController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) suggests that type online is: "internet based", i.e. not only local Wifi.